# AMDGPU-PRO install fails in Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, 16.10

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 with an AMD R9 380. I downloaded the AMDGPU-PRO drivers from here: [AMDGPU-PRO install instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)

I followed the instructions on the same page up to the point where you run the **amdgpu-pro-install** script.

Here is the output:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install
tee: /etc/aptsources.list.d/amdgpu-pro.list: No such file or directory
deb file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro/ ./
```

I wasn't able to find tee in the repositories.

Comment: The command to start the install as listed on the AMD website is `amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install`, not `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`. the Tee command is part of the coreutils package. @Giammaria FYI I've used amdgpu-pro on kernels 4.4, 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9rc1 albeit with Plasma rather than Gnome

Comment: However you run the script, it still fails.

Comment: That path should be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Looks like a bug in the installer to me. Please report it to AMD. Bug reports are off topic on Ubuntu.

Comment: This fixed help me get pass this error -> http://askubuntu.com/a/839059/609672